# how to create new photo album for facebook with iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm able to push a image from my iPhone to the facebook wall successfully. But when I try to push my 2nd image the image is uploaded successfully on the wall but appears side-by-side instead of appearing as the different wall post.

This is because the images uploaded will be added to the same photo album. **So is there any way to push these images to new album so that every album contains 1 image?**

Comment: I would unfriend you if you did this on my feed... I class this as spamming :)

Answer (score 7):

1. First make sure you have publish_stream permission to create a new album.
2. Then to create a new album, make a Graph API call to https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums with parameters for the access token, the album name, and the album description. If the album is created successfully the new album ID will be returned.
3. Then make a call to https://graph.facebook.com/NEW_ALBUM_ID/photos with the access token and other photo parameters to upload your photo to the new album.

By default, if you do not specify any album and just push photos to the me/photos endpoint your photos will end up in an album automatically created for your application.