# How create some photo albums Facebook SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I publish some photos to Facebook, for example:

```
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < 5; idx++){
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: @"me/photos"
parameters: params
HTTPMethod: @"POST"
completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
id result,
NSError *error) {
[self requestCompleted:connection withResult:result andError:error];
}];
}
```

and this photos published in default photo album to Facebook (appName photos). How create new photo album in current iteration?

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664256/how-to-create-new-photo-album-for-facebook-with-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem, i need this string :

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramsToCreateAlbum = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"album ", @"name",
        @"description", @"message", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: @"me/albums"
                             parameters: paramsToCreateAlbum
                             HTTPMethod: @"POST"
                      completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              id result,
                              NSError *error) {

                          if (!error) {
                              //publish content to albumID
                              [self publishContentToAlbum:[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
                          }
                          else {
                              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                          }
                      }];
```